# equals method overrides equals in superclass and may not be symmetric

Tags: java

I have below Findbugs error for my "equal" method,

> This class defines an equals method
>   that overrides an equals method in a
>   superclass. Both equals methods
>   methods use instanceof in the
>   determination of whether two objects
>   are equal. This is fraught with peril,
>   since it is important that the equals
>   method is symmetrical (in other words,
>   a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)). If B is a
>   subtype of A, and A's equals method
>   checks that the argument is an
>   instanceof A, and B's equals method
>   checks that the argument is an
>   instanceof B, it is quite likely that
>   the equivalence relation defined by
>   these methods is not symmetric.

I can not post the code here for security violataion. Please let me know what is the error?

Comment: If you don't post some representative code, it's going to be difficult to see the error...

Comment: He simply needs an explanation of the findbugs "error". No code needed, to my opinion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It says that the contract of `equals()` implies that, `a.equals(b)` is true if and only if `b.equals(a)` is true.

If B extends A, in `A.equals(Object obj)` you probably will have

```
if !(obj instanceof A) return false;
```

and in `B.equals(Object obj)` you will have

```
if !(obj instanceof B) return false;
```

Here is the asymmetry: an instance of B makes (`b instanceof A`) true, while an instance of A makes (`a instanceof B`) false. So it means a risk than `a.equals(b)` is true and `b.equals(a)` is false.

Comment: EQ_OVERRIDING_EQUALS_NOT_SYMMETRIC

Answer (score 5):

You can use the similar construction to prevent this error:

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
   if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass())
   {
      return false;
   } 
// ...
```

instead of

```
public boolean equals(final Object obj)
{
   if (!(o instanceof UniversalIDDefinition))
   {
      return false;
   }   
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too :

```
if (obj == null || !MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: object != null
                && MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())
                && Objects.equals(this, object); /*OR*/
Is.such(object)
                && MyClass.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass())
                && Objects.equals(this, object);
http://thetechawesomeness.ideasmatter.info/null-and-interface.html